# Another CSS Menu Thread - trying to highlight parent root - no prior solutions working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I know there are 400 of these threads out there but it seems like everyone's code is a little bit different: I've set up my CSS so that a blue bar appears every time you hover over a page in the navigation, and when that link page is clicked, the blue bar stays over it. I CAN NOT get it to stay over the parent page when I click on one of the links with a drop-down menu. I'm able to get a blue bar to appear inside of the dropdown (lol) but can not get it to stay with the parent at all. I've tried all the ancestor tips, all the menu-current tips, i'm just at wits end. I would be eternally grateful for any help.

```
        /*** ----------------------------CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE SQUARES UNDERNEATH THE NAVIGATION BAR HERE ------------------------------- ***/
    nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.current {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #00BCF2;
        color: #00BCF2;
    }

    /*** THIS WILL PROBABILY GET US TO WHERE WE WANT TO BE WITH ADDING AND HOVERING THE PARENT LINK 



     nav ul li:hover > a, .current-menu-ancestor > a, .current-menu-parent > a {
            background-color: #536f9e !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }
        ***/

    /*** add publications from box site level 1 here ***/
    /**** Dropdown ****/
    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE LOGO OF THE DROPDOWN ARROW ------------------------------ ***/



    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE height OF THE DROPDOWN menu ------------------------------ ***/

    .dropdown{
        padding: 14px 16px 37px 10px;
        background: url('images/dropdown_icon.png') no-repeat 99% 21px;
    }
    .dropdown:hover{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    nav ul ul{
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #000;
        z-index: 1;

    }
    nav ul li:hover  ul{
        display: block;
            opacity: 0.9;


    }
    nav ul li ul li{
        margin: 0;



    }
    /*** ----------------------------- CHANGE THE WIDTH OF THE DROPDOWN MENU ------------------------------ ***/
    nav ul li ul li a{ 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    /*** ----------------------------- CREATE BLUE BARS INSIDE OF DROPDOWN ------------------------------ ***/

    nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover, nav ul li:hover ul li a.current{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
```

As Requested, The HTML I have for my beginning --> header is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>XXXXXX</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass('current');
    }
    <!--END OF HEADER -->
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--========================== L O G O  &   N A V    B A R ============================-->
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="home.html"><img src="images/xylophone.png" alt="YouRock" /></a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Founders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">Pipeline</a>
                        <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Phases.html">Phase I / II</a></li>
                            <li><a href="preclinical.html">PreClinical</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">Publications</a>
                        <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="publications1.html">Coronary Artery Disease </a></li>
                            <li><a href="publications2.html">Heart Failure</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: html could be useful too , so we can help, the best a code snippet or a codepen/jsfiddle that one can update and explain ...

Comment: Updated with my heading / beginning of the HTML

Comment: As everyone can see - I basically have my border as : border-bottom: 5px solid #00BCF2; - I'd just like this to remain showing up after I click on the child link in the dropdown menu : )